# can I make std::list insert new elements with order ? or got to use std::sort?

Tags: c++, stl

If I want to use `std::list` and that the new elements inserted to the list will be inserted to the right position in relation to a compare function - can I do it ?
or I have to use std::sort after each insertion?

Comment: Sort after each insertion, or find the correct place to begin with and insert there.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking when typing my answer @songyuanyao, which I augmented with Joachim's comment.

Comment: You can't use `std::sort` anyway. You could have checked that.

Comment: Please, please, please do not use `std::list` for anything! Except in certain very specific instances, almost any other data structure will perform better.

Comment: @juanchopanza I cant use std::sort fot std::list ?!

Comment: No, you can't. But you can try it out before asking hypothetical questions.

Comment: I checked here before I asked..

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

- std::set if your elements a immutable
- std::map if your elements have immutable keys, but should have mutable values
- std::list and looking up the insertion position

std::list with std::lower_bound:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> list;
    int values[] = { 7, 2, 5,3, 1, 6, 4};
    for(auto i : values)
        list.insert(std::lower_bound(list.begin(), list.end(), i), i);
    for(auto i : list)
        std::cout << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Alternatively you may populate an entire std::vector and sort it afterwards (Note: std::sort can not operate on std::list::iterators, they do not provide random access):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector = { 7, 2, 5,3, 1, 6, 4};
    std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end());
    for(auto i : vector)
        std::cout << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Note:** The performance of a list with manual lookup of the insertion position is the worst O(N²).

Comment: I am cautious about O notation, due to overhead.  I did an experiment inserting random numbers into (sorted) list, set, and vector; set became faster than list at a size of 50, and set became faster than vector at a size of 67.  If you need very many small sorted containers, set might not be the best choice.

Comment: Do you mean std::lower_bound is O(N)? According to the documentation it belongs to the binary search algorithm, which makes it O(log N) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound#Complexity. In fact both algorithms you propose provide O(N log N) performance

Comment: Good answer, except I also question the "Note:" at the end that the insertion is O(N^2) worst case, from the docs http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/ it appears the insertion with std::lower_bound is O(ln(N))

Comment: O(N^2) seems incorrect. From a theoretical perspective, inserting into a sorted linked list maintaining sort order should be at worst O(n). Simply enumerate through the list until the right position is located and do an O(1) insert. Alternatively, if you can use a more economical datastructure for the search (e.g. a red-black tree) you should be able to solve the problem with an O(log n) find and O(1) insert into the linked list.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Try something like following, just change compare function and type if needed.

```
#include <list>

inline
int compare(int& a, int&b) {
    return a - b;
}

template<typename T>
void insert_in_order(std::list<T>& my_list, T element, int (*compare)(T& a, T&b)) {
    auto begin = my_list.begin();
    auto end = my_list.end();
    while ( (begin != end) &&
        ( compare(*begin,element) < 0 )      ) {
        ++begin;
    }
    my_list.insert(begin, element);
}

int main() {
    std::list<int> my_list = { 5,3,2,1 };
    my_list.sort();                              //list == { 1,2,3,5}
    insert_in_order<int>(my_list, 4, &compare);  //list == {1,2,3,4,5}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

1. Sort after every insertion
2. Find the right index and insert at that index
3. Use an [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) (recommended)

Example for third option:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  int myints[] = {75,23,65,42,13};
  std::set<int> myset (myints,myints+5);

  std::cout << "myset contains:";
  for (std::set<int>::iterator it=myset.begin(); it!=myset.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> myset contains: 13 23 42 65 75

Comment: Why I got a downvote? If there is a bug I would like to know please.